# Datepicker setData displays incorrect date on dateFormat 'MM yy'

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm working with a datepicker that only needs to show and pick the month and the year. So I changed the dateFormat to 'MM yy'. Now when I do:

```
$('.date-picker').datepicker('setDate', 'July 2016');
```

The datepicker shows January 2022. But when I do:

```
console.log($('.date-picker').datepicker("getDate"));
```

It shows Tue Jul 19 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (PHT)

I tried changing the dateFormat to 'MM dd yy' and setDate to 'July 01 2016' and it works smoothly.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gaddygs3/3/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#txtDate').datepicker({
 changeMonth: true,
 changeYear: true,
 dateFormat: 'MM yy',

 onClose: function() {
    var iMonth = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
    var iYear = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
 },

 beforeShow: function() {
   if ((selDate = $(this).val()).length > 0) 
   {
      iYear = selDate.substring(selDate.length - 4, selDate.length);
      iMonth = jQuery.inArray(selDate.substring(0, selDate.length - 5), $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
      $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
       $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
   }
}
});
});
```

[Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/2NVRD/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=2NVRD)

Comment: It turns out I need to provide a random day right? Thanks :)

Comment: Aaa..Sorry I didn't get it just clarify me.

Comment: What I wanted to do is to show a initial date which is from a controller. So I will pass the current Month and Year to the datepicker. For example July and 2016, from that, I will set the date of the datepicker. I'm sorry I didn't include this in my question earlier :|

Comment: Okay I understood let me some time.

Comment: Hey @ranjan thanks I've got it working. I learned that January is 0 in datepicker. So I thought July being 6 is wrong. Thank you very much for your input, it helped :)

Comment: @WreighChristianSantos its my pleasure.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly change the format of setting the date

```
$('#checkin').datepicker('setDate',new Date('July 2016'));
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand :|